# instantiating SemanticSettings is causing a build error in web app

Tags: c#, semantic-search

The following line of code is causing a build error:

SemanticSettings semanticSettings = new SemanticSettings();

This came from [Quickstart: semantic ranking - Azure AI Search | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-semantic?tabs=dotnet)

I was able to follow the tutorial but when I copied the code into my web app it would not compile.  Any idea why?  I’ve attached the file I’m editing as well as the build log file.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Kenneth

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft support confirmed that they needed to update their code and help documentation.  The thread can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1466163/instantiating-semanticsettings-is-causing-a-build?comment=question#comment-1467117

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).